# Flycheck- check python module import

Tags: python, flycheck

I was wondering how I can make Flycheck check the modules imported in a python file - to check if function used from a module is correct or not. Is there another mode which is able to do that for me?

For example:

```
import utils
str = utils.chk("is this right?")
```

How can I make flycheck(or any other checker) check if the imported file utils contains a function called chk?

I'm currently using python-mode on Emacs 24.4 with pylint and flake8 as checkers for Flycheck on Windows 8.1 64 bit. I also have semantic installed.

Can that help me in anyway?

Comment: I think something called Pyflake... but I may be wrong.

Comment: you can emacs-jedi. jedi doesn't highlight errors, but when you keep your cursor on the line `import utils` and do `Alt - .` (`goto-definition`), it takes you to the module file itself.

Comment: I know about Jedi. Isn't that for auto completion? Though I just want a checker that checks if the functions I use from any modules are defined and take the correct amount arguments and not go to it's definition or auto complete them for me(Yes, I'm not a big fan of auto complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this occurrence was quite simple. I assumed that both flake8 and pylint were running together but in reality only flake8 was running as the flycheck's syntax checker. I changed it to python-pylint and now it works as expected.

To do this, just type `M-x flycheck-select-checker` and enter `python-pylint` (make sure you install pylint for flycheck from melpa first)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pylint with flymake.
http://docs.pylint.org/ide-integration

UPDATE:
I use emacs 24.5 with this configuration:

```
 (autoload 'flymake-mode "flymake" nil t)
               (eval-after-load "flymake"
                 '(progn 
                    (require 'flymake-cursor)
                    (defun flymake-pylint-init ()
                      (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                                         'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
                             (local-file (file-relative-name temp-file (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
                        (list "epylint" (list local-file))))
                    (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pylint-init))))
```

Here a screenshot of the control:
[image]

Comment: Flymake was the old checker for emacs. Flycheck (for emacs 24) is supposed to be a great improvement on that. I believe pylint (and flake8) works with Flycheck out of the box. And so it seems that pylint doesn't flag errors on module imports.

Comment: @Milap Sheth. Maybe you can use Flycheck instead of Flymake (I don't know why it is better but will try it). But I had a screenshot to show you an example of error on module imports.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I'm already using Flycheck as I mentioned in the question. I thought that the particular error E1101 might be disabled in some .pylintrc file although it isn't. So, I don't exactly know why this error is not being shown. The reason I insist on using Flycheck is that it works with many languages and no additional code is required like with Flymake. So, I want to fix the error with flycheck instead of using flymake.

Comment: What should I do to use this function? should I add a keybinding for it? @djangoliv

Comment: @alper. M-x flymake on python buffer.