# Flycheck Python introspection into modules?

Tags: python, flycheck, ide

I have flycheck working seemingly as advertised with Python on Emacs 25.2.1.

The configuration check shows all dependencies are satisfied and enabled. It does handle introspection within the same file, but for my imports it does not introspect into those objects to verify if the attributes exist in that object.  For example:

```
from modules import some_module

some_module.some_function(some_arg) # some_function does not exist, should highlight
```

The jedi-youcompleteme is able to drill down into those imported objects to get the docstrings, and I am wondering if flycheck is capable of drilling down as well.

I have tried the advice to run `M-x flycheck-select-checker` then 'python-pylint' as recommended at [Flycheck- check python module import](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13823/flycheck-check-python-module-import) but it had no effect.

I'm a daily IdeaUltimate user but have also used Emacs for some time when in a terminal and want to use it on the desktop as well.